# how to use group by with inner join

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have three tables **customer** , **bargains** and **installment**.
I want to select *name* from **customer** table and sum of *total price* from **bargains** table and sum of *payment amount* from **installment** table according to each customer and at the end subtract the sum of total price from sum of payment amount.
so the result should be a list that contain name of all customers and their debt.

I try the following command but it return wrong values it looks like they are summed twice or maybe more.

```
select c.name, b.total_price, i.payment_amount
from customer as c
inner join (select sell_or_buy, sum(total_price) as total_price from     bargains group by C_ID ) as b on (b.sell_or_buy = 'خرید')
inner join (select trade_type, sum(payment_amount) as payment_amount from installment group by C_ID ) as i on (i.trade_type = 'پرداخت')
group by c.C_ID
```

because I thought query sum the total price for each record of installment table and sum the payment amount for each record of bargains table I try to use select in inner joins to make each of them distinct but it doesn't work
so I couldn't even subtract the results.
I also try the following query

```
select
(select sum(payment_amount) as payment_amount from installment  where trade_type = 'پرداخت'group by C_ID)-
(select sum(total_price) as total_price from bargains where sell_or_buy = 'خرید' group by C_ID)as result
```

which display and error which say query return more than one row.
when I use only one select from above query the result is OK but when I try to combine the its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original query seems to be missing the correct join conditions.  Try this instead:

```
select c.name,
       b.total_price,
       i.payment_amount
from customer as c
inner join
(
    select C_ID, sum(total_price) as total_price
    from bargains
    where sell_or_buy = 'خرید'
    group by C_ID
) as b
    on c.C_ID = b.C_ID
inner join
(
    select C_ID, sum(payment_amount) as payment_amount
    from installment
    where trade_type = 'پرداخت'
    group by C_ID
) as i
    on c.C_ID = i.C_ID
```

If you want to compute the difference between the total price and payment amount, then just use this `SELECT`:

```
select c.name,
       b.total_price,
       i.payment_amount,
       b.total_price - i.payment_amount AS diff
```

Comment: I just want to know which one is better, subtract the result of these two inner join in sql so I would have two column as result (customer name and debt) as I mention in question or when i receive the result of query in php and then subtract them inside a loop row by row. if the first choice is better then how should I do that, because i'm new in sql but i can do it in php

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use subquery to do this, just join the three tables and do aggregation, try following:

```
select 
    c.name,
    sum(b.total_price) as total_price,
    sum(i.payment_amount) as payment_amount
from customer as c
inner join bargains b on c.c_id = b.c_id and b.sell_or_buy = 'خرید'
inner join installment i on c.c_id = i.c_id and i.trade_type = 'پرداخت'
group by c.c_id   -- ,c.name
```

and like @Tim Biegeleisen said, if the `sql_mode` of your mysql db contains `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, you should also add `c.name` in `group by` clause.
and use this query to check `sql_mode`:

```
show variables like 'sql_mode';
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give me an actual screen shot of each of the tables with a few entries in them?

You're probably getting duplicate rows because of this line:
inner join (select trade_type, sum(payment_amount) as payment_amount from installment group by C_ID )

basically, you probably shouldn't use the sum() function while also selecting values from any other field. Here's why: sum(payment_amount) should return 1 row correct? But right next to it you've got "select trade_type" which probably is going to return multiple rows.

Also, what language is this? MySQL? SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Subquery:

```
SELECT c.Id AS CustomerId, c.Name AS CustomerName, m.Name AS ManagerName, o.SumAmmount 
FROM Customers AS c
INNER JOIN Managers AS m ON c.ManagerId = m.Id
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) AS SumAmmount, o.CustomerId
 FROM Orders AS o
 WHERE Date >= '2017-01-01'
 GROUP BY CustomerId
 HAVING SUM(Amount) >= 10000) AS o ON c.Id = o.CustomerId
```

No Subquery:

```
SELECT c.Id AS CustomerId, c.Name AS CustomerName, 
       m.Name AS ManagerName, SUM(o.Amount) AS SumAmmount 
FROM Customers AS c
INNER JOIN Managers AS m ON c.ManagerId = m.Id
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON c.Id = o.CustomerId
WHERE o.Date >= '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY c.Id, c.Name, m.Name
HAVING SUM(Amount) >= 10000
```